# How to access Procress Variables using the Remoting API

Tags: jbpm

I have a process running on the workbench that comes with the JBPM Demo. I can successfully start a process with a Map of Process Variables. In the following user task, I need to retrieve the process variables to display on the GUI. I can successfully retrieve the Process Instance. On the non-remoting API I would cast the process instance into its actual class of RuleFlowProcessInstance and call the getVariable method. When I use the Remoting API, the Process Instance is of type JaxbProcessInstanceResponse and does not have a getVariable method. Is there some other way to look up process variables while using the Remoting API? Below is my code to obtain the process instance.

```
url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8080/jbpm-console");
restFactory = new RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory(
    DEPLOYMENT_ID, url, JMS_USER, JMS_PASS);
engine = restFactory.newRuntimeEngine();
session = engine.getKieSession();
List<TaskSummary> list = taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner(
    user, LANGUAGE);
for(TaskSummary summary : list) {
    ProcessInstance pi = session.getProcessInstance(
        summary.getProcessInstanceId());
    JaxbProcessInstanceResponse resp = (JaxbProcessInstanceResponse)pi;
    //TODO: somehow lookup Process Variables
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use AuditLogService interface.

```
AuditService audit = engine.getAuditLogService();
```

I think for your purpose using the *findVariableInstances(long processInstanceId, String variableId)* method will be fine.

Check available AuditLogService methods from documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html#remote.java.api.jms), table 17.12

Comment: The methods you mentioned work to as described; however, the process variables are Java Objects and no Strings. Are there any other methods that return a Java Object as the value instead of the String? If there isn't, I supposed I could override the toString method to write a JSON representation or some other serializable form.